# Time Ticks: 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001

Tags: python

Is there a python function similar to .net DateTime.Ticks which gives 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001?  Tried datetime and time modules and so far I'm only able to get Unix epoch time.

Comment: Bear in mind that the current calendar system (the Gregorian calendar) was not in use during the year "1". (And even that requires a calendar to state when it was.) Be aware of what calendar system your dates are in, and what calendar system(s) any code you use uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion from seconds since the UNIX epoch to time ticks is easy enough:

```
>>> int((datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) - datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).total_seconds()) * (10 ** 7)
621355968000000000
```

Just add 621355968000000000 to time ticks since the epoch; time ticks since the epoch is simply the timestamp times 10^7:

```
import time

def timestamp_to_ticks(t=None):
    if t is None:
        t = time.time()
    return int(t * (10**7)) + 621355968000000000
```